# CWEs for Language Machine Learning Models

Tags: machine-learning, cwe

I'm looking for the relevant CWE's for specific attacks against prompt-based language ML models, such as GPT-3, GPT-4 etc.

Specifically:

- [Prompt Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prompt_engineering#Malicious): Amending prompts with malicious input to change the output of the model in ways not intended by the model owner/operator.
- Prompt Lookbehind: Variation of Prompt Injection which allows a malicious user to examine the non-public parts of the prompt (Example: [Bing's 'Sydney'](https://twitter.com/marvinvonhagen/status/1623658144349011971))

Excuse the quality of the definitions I've provided, I'm more interested in what sort of CWEs cover these types of weaknesses and how specific they can get rather than drafting accurate definitions. Perhaps [CWE-1039](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/1039.html) may cover them both but I wonder if I should be using more generic CWEs or if there are any more specific to the specific weaknesses above.

Comment: i'm not sure the "common" qualifier applies in this case? .. interesting reading about "Sydney" - do you think the whole exchange is "hallucinated" as one commenter wondered? anyway, love the exchange "what would happen if we ... `cd .sydney` then `ls -la` ... etc" haha stupid helpful corruptible robot `(:`

Comment: The increasing utilisation of those sorts of models might justify having more specific CWEs if they don't already exist, regardless, you've identified the crux of my question. Which are the most specific CWEs for these weaknesses without choosing CWEs which are too general?